# Background move to left when I open a modal-lg

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

When I open modal-lg, the background screen moves to the left. I tried many ways, but it failed. Please see the code and change accordingly I am using Bootstrap 4. Thank you.

When I open modal-lg, the background screen moves to the left. I tried many ways, but it failed. Please see the code and change accordingly I am using Bootstrap 4. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade mt-5 " id="myModal2@(count)">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg " style=" padding-left: 0 !important;">
    <div class="modal-content">


      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h6 class="modal-title Bold">ویرایش قرارداد</h6>

      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form asp-controller="AmorMalie" asp-action="EditSubmitGhrardad" method="post">

          <table class="table table-bordered text-sm ">

            <thead class="text-center">

              <tr style="background-color:#416992; color: white">
                <th>نام پروژه</th>

                <th>نوع خدمات</th>
                <th>مبلغ قرارداد (ریال)</th>
                <th style="width:80px">ت ج ماه</th>
                <th style="width:130px">ارزش افزوده</th>

              </tr>

            </thead>

            <tr>

              <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="hf_selected_val" value="@item.projectID" />

                <select class="form-control " name="projectID" required autocomplete="off">

                  <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                  @foreach (var items in ViewBag.pros) {
                  <option value="@items.projectID">@items.projectName</option>
                  }




                </select>

              </td>

              <input class="d-none" name="id" value="@item.id" />
              <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="hf_selected_val" value="@item.NoeaKhadmat" />
                <select class="form-control" name="NoeaKhadmat" required autocomplete="off">

                  <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                  <option value="1">حسابرسی</option>
                  <option value="2">مالیاتی</option>
                  <option value="3">منابع انسانی</option>
                </select>

              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control num" name="MablghGhrardad" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=itpro(this.value);" value="@item.MablghGhrardad" autocomplete="off" /></td>

              <td><input class="form-control num" name="TadadJelse" autocomplete="off" value="@item.TadadJalaseDrMoaheGhrardad" /></td>



              <td class="text-center">

                <input type="checkbox" name="MashmolArzeshAfzoode" @(item.MashmolArzeshAfzoode ? "checked" : "") style="width: 1.25rem; height: 1.25rem; top: .8rem; " class="flat-red" value="True">

              </td>

            </tr>

            <thead class="text-center mr-3">

              <tr style="background-color:#416992; color: white">
                <th>تاریخ شروع</th>
                <th>تاریخ پایان</th>
                <th style="background-color:darkgreen">تعین کارشناس</th>
                <th colspan="2" class="text-center">عملیات</th>

              </tr>

            </thead>

            <tr>
              <td>


                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                  <div class="input-group-addon" style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                    <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input name="bgainDate2" id="bgainDate2@(count)" type="text" autocomplete="off" value=" @ConvertDateTime.ConvertMiladiToShamsi(item.ShoroeeProjectDate, " yyyy/MM/dd ")" class="form-control" />

                </div>

              </td>

              <td>

                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                  <div class="input-group-addon" style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                    <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input name="EndDate2" id="EndDate2@(count)" type="text" autocomplete="off" value=" @ConvertDateTime.ConvertMiladiToShamsi(item.PayanProjectDate, " yyyy/MM/dd ")" class="form-control" />

                </div>


              </td>


              <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="hf_selected_val" value="@item.UserID" />
                <select class="form-control" name="TaeenKarShnas" autocomplete="off">

                  <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                  @foreach (var items in ViewBag.userss) {
                  <option value="@items.Id">@items.FirstName @items.Family</option>
                  }

                </select>

              </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="color:white">ویرایش قرارداد</button>
              </td>


            </tr>
          </table>

        </form>


      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@{count++;}
```

Comment: Hi @stoo frisat, I think you may share more html code. I cannot reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and it works perfectly. You do an external CSS or internal CSS. Your choice. If you want internal. Just do a `<style> insert the CSS here </style`

CSS:

```
body:not(.modal-open){
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Internal CSS:

```
<style>
 body:not(.modal-open){
      padding-right: 0px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Full code:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade mt-5 " id="myModal2@(count)">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg " style=" padding-left: 0 !important;">
    <div class="modal-content">


      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h6 class="modal-title Bold">ویرایش قرارداد</h6>

      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form asp-controller="AmorMalie" asp-action="EditSubmitGhrardad" method="post">

          <table class="table table-bordered text-sm ">

            <thead class="text-center">

              <tr style="background-color:#416992; color: white">
                <th>نام پروژه</th>

                <th>نوع خدمات</th>
                <th>مبلغ قرارداد (ریال)</th>
                <th style="width:80px">ت ج ماه</th>
                <th style="width:130px">ارزش افزوده</th>

              </tr>

            </thead>

            <tr>

              <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="hf_selected_val" value="@item.projectID" />

                <select class="form-control " name="projectID" required autocomplete="off">

                  <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                  @foreach (var items in ViewBag.pros) {
                  <option value="@items.projectID">@items.projectName</option>
                  }




                </select>

              </td>

              <input class="d-none" name="id" value="@item.id" />
              <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="hf_selected_val" value="@item.NoeaKhadmat" />
                <select class="form-control" name="NoeaKhadmat" required autocomplete="off">

                  <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                  <option value="1">حسابرسی</option>
                  <option value="2">مالیاتی</option>
                  <option value="3">منابع انسانی</option>
                </select>

              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control num" name="MablghGhrardad" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=itpro(this.value);" value="@item.MablghGhrardad" autocomplete="off" /></td>

              <td><input class="form-control num" name="TadadJelse" autocomplete="off" value="@item.TadadJalaseDrMoaheGhrardad" /></td>



              <td class="text-center">

                <input type="checkbox" name="MashmolArzeshAfzoode" @(item.MashmolArzeshAfzoode ? "checked" : "") style="width: 1.25rem; height: 1.25rem; top: .8rem; " class="flat-red" value="True">

              </td>

            </tr>

            <thead class="text-center mr-3">

              <tr style="background-color:#416992; color: white">
                <th>تاریخ شروع</th>
                <th>تاریخ پایان</th>
                <th style="background-color:darkgreen">تعین کارشناس</th>
                <th colspan="2" class="text-center">عملیات</th>

              </tr>

            </thead>

            <tr>
              <td>


                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                  <div class="input-group-addon" style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                    <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input name="bgainDate2" id="bgainDate2@(count)" type="text" autocomplete="off" value=" @ConvertDateTime.ConvertMiladiToShamsi(item.ShoroeeProjectDate, " yyyy/MM/dd ")" class="form-control" />

                </div>

              </td>

              <td>

                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                  <div class="input-group-addon" style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                    <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input name="EndDate2" id="EndDate2@(count)" type="text" autocomplete="off" value=" @ConvertDateTime.ConvertMiladiToShamsi(item.PayanProjectDate, " yyyy/MM/dd ")" class="form-control" />

                </div>


              </td>


              <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="hf_selected_val" value="@item.UserID" />
                <select class="form-control" name="TaeenKarShnas" autocomplete="off">

                  <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                  @foreach (var items in ViewBag.userss) {
                  <option value="@items.Id">@items.FirstName @items.Family</option>
                  }

                </select>

              </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="color:white">ویرایش قرارداد</button>
              </td>


            </tr>
          </table>

        </form>


      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button>
      </div>
    enter code here

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@{count++;}

    // this is internal css
<style>
 body:not(.modal-open){
      padding-right: 0px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Where should I put this code. Please give an example with my code. Thank you

Comment: Just do an internal css. Open and close style. See the updated answer,

Comment: This code did not work for me.What is this .modal-open class?

Comment: I have to call this class in code ? Please give an example with my code

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: I applied the code but unfortunately it did not work